# Last online php

Tags: php

I am using a simple script at the top of every page that will update a LastActive column in the database:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if(isset($username, $userID)) {

    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Users SET lastActive = DATE_ADD(Now(), interval 6 hour) WHERE username = ?")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            $insert_stmt->close();
            header('Location: ../headers/error.php?err=Failed Upload');
        }
    }
    $insert_stmt->close();
}
```

I always want to keep performance and security in mind. Would this lead to poor performance in the future with 000's of connections?

How does using cookies (not that I know how) differ from a simple script like this?

Thanks

edit:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$loginTime = $_SESSION['timestamp'];
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$now = new DateTime();
$diff=$now->diff($loginTime);
$minutes = $diff->format(%i);

if(isset($username, $userID) && $minutes> 30) {
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = $now;
    $online = true;
}
```

Comment: 1. obviously that is an additional and expensive database query which does not help with the service provided, so it is negative from a performance point of view. 2. I don't see _any_ reason in displaying some error page if that purely internal value storage fails, whyever. Just swallow and log the error, but don't annoy your users with it. 3. a "last logged in" value always strikes me as one of those "features" that are done just because it is possible. Don't. If at all, then not with a separate query, but when updating the database anyway.

Comment: You're isset is on variables that will be set regardless... Furthermore, they should in fact be on the $_SESSION variables.

I agree with the above, but shouldn't you maybe do this by the hour? Check in the $_SESSION if lastActive is within the last hour and if so ignore, otherwise update it. Would save you 60 requests, assuming the open a page every minute.

Comment: `Users.username` is indexed, I presume.

Comment: Would it be better to, on login set $_SESSION['timestamp'] = now, then update session value every 30 mins? And have the code atop of every page. Rather than running sql codes? (code edit on op)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd post the way I got around this for any one else looking for a User Online type method. Of course this might have been done much better but works in my situation.

---

I am using both database entries and session to test if a user is online.

On user login I update a column in my users table with a `Now()` timestamp and add this to their session data.

At the top of each page I am running a script to check if the user is logged in and get their timestamp from session data. if this data is 45 minutes old, the script will update the table setting the `lastActive` column of my users table to `Now();`

```
<?php
include_once 'functions.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['lastActive'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
    $now = new DateTime();
    $lastActive = $_SESSION['lastActive'];
    $diff=$now->diff($lastActive);
    $hours = $diff->format('%h');
    $mins = $diff->format('%i');
    $day = $diff->format('%d');
    $month = $diff->format('%m');
    $year = $diff->format('%y');



    if($mins > 45 || $hours >= 1 || $day >= 1 || $month >= 1 || $year >= 1) {
        $_SESSION['lastActive'] = $now;
        set_last_active($mysqli, $_SESSION['username']);
    }
}
```

set_latst_action is simply just:

```
function set_last_active($mysqli, $username) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Users SET lastActive = Now() WHERE username = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

then when I want to see if a user is online for example on a profile page I call `isOnline();`

```
function isOnline($mysqli, $username) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT lastActive FROM Users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            $stmt->bind_result($return);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $lastActive = $return;

        } else {
            // user does not exist
            $lastActive = "";
            return $lastActive;
            $stmt->close();
        }
    } else {
        // SELECT failed
        $lastActive = "";
        return $lastActive;
        $stmt->close();
    }

    if (!empty($lastActive)) {
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
        $dateNow = new DateTime;
        $lastActiveDate = new DateTime($lastActive);
        $diff=$dateNow->diff($lastActiveDate);

        $hours = $diff->format('%h');
        $mins = $diff->format('%i');
        $day = $diff->format('%d');
        $month = $diff->format('%m');
        $year = $diff->format('%y');

        if ($mins > 45 || $hours >= 1 || $days >= 1 || $month >= 1 || $year >= 1) {
            $return = "Offline";
            return $return;
        }
        else {
            $return = "Online";
            return $return;
        }
    } 
    else {
        $return = "Offline";
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions:

1. You could do this via AJAX, so that the LastVisited is updated asynchronously after the user's page loads. That way, there won't be any impact to the page load time for the user.
2. If, for any reason, your SQL query fails, you should fail silently. Since recording Last Visited is not business critical, you should not redirect the user to an error page. Maybe just log an error, and set up an alert so if there are multiple failures, you get alerted and can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

All that you made with cookies will be data supplied by your users, then you cannot trust it.

In other hand, if you work with cookies, all of them will travel in each request header.

You should do it in server side and yes, a database is not performant.

You can try to persist this information with something like [Redis](http://redis.io/), a in-memory data structure store, used as database, cache and message broker.