# Last time a user was logged in / browsing the website

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to set up a notifications system that doesn't requiere cookies.
I'm using SQL to store my users's info, and they are then passed into `$_SESSION['user_auth']` once they are logged in.

When a user logs in, I want to fetch the last time the user was online (for instance 05/05/2016 21:35:50) and then compare with the database if there's any more recent announcements, posterior to its "last time logged in".

Is this viable ?

How can I know the last time my user was browsing the website ? Do I need a new row in my `'users'` table, if so, how to set this function up ?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: PHP sessions require cookies :O

Comment: Short answer: sure, it's feasible. You would likely need to track a "last seen" date in your `users` table (a new column). When you decide to update it is up to you (e.g. could be every page load, every action, every click, etc.). You could also maintain the date in session (memory) and write it out when their session ends to avoid multiple database hits.

Comment: Just like C mentioned. The best way to achieve this after creating the extra colomn in your database table is to add the time update query to your functions page which would probably be included in all your pages

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so, the idea of updating a "last seen" row every time the user loads a page would actually work I guess, but I prefere the second solution, writing it in the database only when the session ends since the db wouldn't have to be overloaded with requests. However how can this be set up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a similar method I created and you can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395924/last-online-php)
The basic idea is updating a `lastActive` column in the database and update this upon user login and set a session variable to the current time. Then at the top of each page is a function that checks a users activity. If the time between last login and current time is above 45minutes then the `lastActive` data in MySQL is updated.

You can use the following function to set and update the lastActive column and use your own methods for 'when' this function can be used.

```
function set_last_active($mysqli, $username) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Users SET lastActive = Now() WHERE username = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

This is what I use as a script at the top of each page:

```
<?php
include_once 'functions.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['lastActive'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
    $now = new DateTime();
    $lastActive = $_SESSION['lastActive'];
    $diff=$now->diff($lastActive);
    $hours = $diff->format('%h');
    $mins = $diff->format('%i');
    $day = $diff->format('%d');
    $month = $diff->format('%m');
    $year = $diff->format('%y');



    if($mins > 45 || $hours >= 1 || $day >= 1 || $month >= 1 || $year >= 1) {
        $_SESSION['lastActive'] = $now;
        set_last_active($mysqli, $_SESSION['username']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is going to be really useful, and it doesn't overload the database with requests. I was disapointed there wasn't a native feature in mySQL for this kind of thing but this should do the trick, I'm going to try that out right now. Thanks !

Comment: Just one small thing about your script, would that work with the `time()` function ? The UNIX timestamp (seconds since 01/01/1970) would allow to get rid of the min/hour/year conversion I guess.

Comment: The script will need a little re-arranging to allow for time() and I am due to update the script soon to include this way of time differencing. However feel free to update it to allow the use of time() rather than using date diff's :)

Comment: You could keep the script as it is an use (how I am going to update this script in the future) `$diff = $lastActive->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();
if ($diff > 0) {
    // update lastActive
}`